# Propagated Domain CAA Records Not Matching Configuration

Tags: dns, cloudflare, ca

I am using Cloudflare DNS and everything mostly works fine but I can't seem to get my CAA records to get saved correctly. The records I want to be present are below:

`0 issuewild letsencrypt.org; validationmethods=dns-01; accounturi=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/<number>`

`0 issue letsencrypt.org; validationmethods=dns-01; accounturi=https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/<number>`

The records are saved and no error is shown so I assume they are correct, but if you try to check the CAA records for my domain (bluecom.dev) with online tools or `host -t type257 bluecom.dev` it shows entirely different records. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or will they propagate eventually? They've been set up this way for a few months so I assume not the latter, but how would I go about making it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, **Let'sEncrypt** is already fulfilled by CloudFlare automatically I'm not sure what are you trying exactly to do.

By the way, CloudFlare adds to `CAA` record automatically this (In order to work with Cloudflare's Universal SSL):

```
example.com. IN CAA 0 issue "comodoca.com"
example.com. IN CAA 0 issue "digicert.com"
example.com. IN CAA 0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
example.com. IN CAA 0 issuewild "comodoca.com"
example.com. IN CAA 0 issuewild "digicert.com"
example.com. IN CAA 0 issuewild "letsencrypt.org"
```

At your domain (`bluecom.dev`) it registers something similar:

```
bluecom.dev. 3600 IN CAA 0 issue "digicert.com cansignhttpexchanges=yes"
bluecom.dev. 3600 IN CAA 0 issuewild "digicert.com cansignhttpexchanges=yes"
bluecom.dev. 3600 IN CAA 0 issue "comodoca.com"
bluecom.dev. 3600 IN CAA 0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
bluecom.dev. 3600 IN CAA 0 issuewild "comodoca.com"
bluecom.dev. 3600 IN CAA 0 issuewild "letsencrypt.org"
```

[image: Adding CAA Record in CloudFlare]

I recommend you to disable CloudFlare Universal SSL, as this is the cause of these records being added automatically as soon as the first CAA record is added; this in order to fix your problem.

But really, I would not recommend adding CAA records or disabling CloudFlare Universal SSL as this is usually only required to maintain policy compliance in very rare cases.

You can learn more about your issue at: [CloudFlare Help Center - CAA](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000310832-Certification-Authority-Authorization-CAA-FAQ#h_645975761191543365946939)

Comment: I watched a tutorial on how to do it and the person there included his account in the CAA record, which is supposedly good protection against spoofing so I did it in a similar way. I later transferred my DNS from Namecheap to Cloudflare because I wanted API access for auto-renew and didn't realize my records weren't being used. Is it really not a problem to allow certificate creation across many sites if I know I will specifically use just one?

Comment: If you're worried about certificate creation spoofing rather than creating a CAA record you can subscribe to CloudFlare transparency notice, this will allow you to know exactly at the moment where a certificate is issued for your domain name without causing any possible future issues.

Comment: "I watched a tutorial on how to do it and the person there included his account in the CAA record, " This is possible now thanks to RFC 8657 and you can even restrict by validation method... as long as the CA understands those records, and you can enable flag "critical". Those are "extensions" over core CAA now in RFC  8659. It also depends what your DNS provider supports, including UI and API wise.